# Why does this binary search return -1 even though the element is in the array

Tags: java, binary-search

It prints out -1 I might be missing how that happens since "Germany" is definitely in the array

```
    public class A 
    {
        static PrintWriter pw = new PrintWriter(System.out, true); 

        public static void main(String[] args) throws IOException 
        {
            String[] a = new String[4];
            a[0]="India";
            a[1]="Italy";
            a[2]="Germany";
            a[3]="India";

            pw.println(Arrays.binarySearch(a, "Germany"));


        }
    }
```

Answer (score 10, accepted):

binary search only works on sorted arrays.

[Arrays API](http://docs.oracle.com/javase/6/docs/api/java/util/Arrays.html#binarySearch%28java.lang.Object%5B%5D,%20int,%20int,%20java.lang.Object%29)

Answer (score 7):

A binary search requires the array to be sorted (heap). You can use [Arrays.sort()](http://docs.oracle.com/javase/7/docs/api/java/util/Arrays.html#sort%28java.lang.Object%5B%5D%29) :

```
public class A 
{
    static PrintWriter pw = new PrintWriter(System.out, true); 

    public static void main(String[] args) throws IOException 
    {
        String[] a = new String[4];
        a[0]="India";
        a[1]="Italy";
        a[2]="Germany";
        a[3]="India";

        Arrays.sort(a);

        pw.println(Arrays.binarySearch(a, "Germany"));


    }
}
```

Note, that this requires the element type to either be a primitive type, or an impementation of the interface [Comparable<T>](http://docs.oracle.com/javase/7/docs/api/java/lang/Comparable.html), which applies for [String](http://docs.oracle.com/javase/7/docs/api/java/lang/String.html).

Answer (score 1):

The list has to be sorted to use binary search